# How can i Convert JSON file With array key in excel with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a JSON file with array key and i want to convert to a excel file with two tables. How can I do this with Python?
This is my JSON file :

```json
[{"information": {"title": " KUWAIT ENERGY CO. KSCC", "Member_No": " 100018", "Auth_Capital":" 127000000",  "Email": " mansour.aboukhamseen@koc.com.kw"}, "users": [{"name": "منصور احمد محمد بوخمسين", "role": "  Chairman of the board of Directors", "nationality": " KUWAIT"},{"name": "محمد عادل التميمي", "role": "  Vice Chairman and Cheif Executive", "nationality": " CANADA"}]},
{"information":{"title": " SALEM INTERNATIONAL ADVERTISING CO.", "Member_No": " 100021",   "Auth_Capital": " 10000",     "Email": null},  "users": [{"name": "SALEM M. AL-AJMI", "role": "  Authorized partner with Doc.", "nationality": " KUWAIT"}]},
{"information":{"title": " POWER TOUCH GEN. TRAD. & CONT. CO.", "Member_No": " 100026",   "Auth_Capital": " 500000",     "Email": null},  "users": [{"name": "ريم محمد سالم الحريص", "role": "  Partner", "nationality": " KUWAIT"},{"name": "محمد 0 0", "role": "  Special Power of Attorney", "nationality": " KUWAIT"}, {"name": "سالم 0 0", "role": "  Special Power of Attorney", "nationality": " KUWAIT"}]}]
```

However i want to convert it to excel table with relation with the two tables many-to-many.

Like this :
The first table contains the information of compagnies:

| title | Member_No | Auth_Capital | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KUWAIT ENERGY CO. KSCC | 100018 | 127000000 | 127000000 |
| SALEM INTERNATIONAL ADVERTISING CO. | 100021 | 10000 |  |
| POWER TOUCH GEN. TRAD. & CONT. CO. | 100026 | 500000 |  |

And for the second table contains the information  of users and the associated company :

| name | role | nationality | Member_No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| منصور احمد محمد بوخمسين | Chairman of the board of Directors | KUWAIT | 100018 |
| محمد عادل التميمي | Vice Chairman and Cheif Executive | CANADA | 100018 |
| SALEM M. AL-AJMI | Authorized partner with Doc. | KUWAIT | 100021 |
| ريم محمد سالم الحريص | Partner | KUWAIT | 100026 |
| محمد | Special Power of Attorney | KUWAIT | 100026 |
| سالم | Special Power of Attorney | KUWAIT | 100026 |

I am still a beginner in Python.

I coded the following code which can convert a simple json file

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('C:/Users/DELL-PC/Desktop/sample.json',encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel('C:/Users/DELL-PC/Desktop/Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: the JSON provided is not a valid JSON. Please provide a valid JSON sample

Comment: I modify the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the data yourself and then create 2 separate dataframes. See the code example below.

**EDIT:** if you need relations between the two tables, you need to add the `Member_No` from the company to each user. I've updated the code to show how.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


def split_data(data):
    users = []
    companies = []
    for item in data:
        for user in item["users"]:
            user["Member_No"] = item["information"]["Member_No"]
            users.append(user)
        companies.append(item["information"])
    return users, companies




with open("jsonfilegoeshere.json") as infile:
    input_data = json.load(infile)


users, companies = split_data(input_data)

users_df = pd.DataFrame(users)
companies_df = pd.DataFrame(companies)
print(users_df)
print("\n\n\n")
print(companies_df)
```

**output**

```
                      name                                  role nationality Member_No
0  منصور احمد محمد بوخمسين    Chairman of the board of Directors      KUWAIT    100018
1        محمد عادل التميمي     Vice Chairman and Cheif Executive      CANADA    100018
2         SALEM M. AL-AJMI          Authorized partner with Doc.      KUWAIT    100021
3     ريم محمد سالم الحريص                               Partner      KUWAIT    100026
4                 محمد 0 0             Special Power of Attorney      KUWAIT    100026
5                 سالم 0 0             Special Power of Attorney      KUWAIT    100026




                                  title Member_No Auth_Capital                             Email
0                KUWAIT ENERGY CO. KSCC    100018    127000000   mansour.aboukhamseen@koc.com.kw
1   SALEM INTERNATIONAL ADVERTISING CO.    100021        10000                              None
2    POWER TOUCH GEN. TRAD. & CONT. CO.    100026       500000                              None
```